# How to update tags, properties of all users

Tags: quickblox

I am new to quickblox, haven't started development yet.

Is it possible for my own server/backend, to update the tags or other properties of all the users. I have read that only the user can update its own properties. Is there an admin user that can update any user. If not then how is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Admin user (Account owner) can update all users' fields through API as well.

Just use Admin user's credentials (login/email, password), login through API and after that you will be able to do it.